# I have a space in my Windows name (C:\Users\Jim Johnson like that) and cannot execute keytool to get SHA1 key

Tags: java, android, ssl, keytool, sha

I am trying to get a SHA1 key for Firebase and have tried to use the command

Jim Johnson is a dummy name btw

`keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Jim Johnson\.android\debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`

And I have pretty much checked everything else (keytool works and environmental variables all checked) but I get an error of

```
Illegal option:  Johnson\.android\debug.keystore
keytool -list [OPTION]...

Lists entries in a keystore

Options:

 -rfc                    output in RFC style
 -alias <alias>          alias name of the entry to process
 -keystore <keystore>    keystore name
 -cacerts                access the cacerts keystore
 -storepass <arg>        keystore password
 -storetype <type>       keystore type
 -providername <name>    provider name
 -addprovider <name>     add security provider by name (e.g. SunPKCS11)
   [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -addprovider
 -providerclass <class>  add security provider by fully-qualified class name
   [-providerarg <arg>]    configure argument for -providerclass
 -providerpath <list>    provider classpath
 -v                      verbose output
 -protected              password through protected mechanism

Use "keytool -?, -h, or --help" for this help message
```

I think it it because I have a space in my name. Haven't seen the people in the tutorials I watched use a space in their name.

Any way to get arond this?

Comment: You basically fail to properly quote a command line argument. The space in the path name is taken as a separator between command line arguments. To avoid this you have to quote the path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes. `"C:\Users\Jim Johnson\.android\debug.keystore"` will get the job done.

Comment: This works, kind of. Apprently I also dont have `debug.keystore` in the '.android' folder...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using android studio, you can easily find your SHA-1 key by opening your project and selecting Gradle from the right side-bar (see image below). Gradle should be available for selection on the right.

Next, follow the folder path Tasks -> android and then double-click signingReport.

Android studio should provide you with several keys, one of which is the SAH-1 you are looking for. This is much easier than using the command line.

[image: screen clipping from android studio on Windows]

Comment: What do you mean by right side bar?

Comment: I added an image to show what I'm referring to. If you cannot see this, select the View menu, Tool Windows, then Gradle.